# Specify customized installation for find_package(Protobuf)

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

Suppose on my machine the protobuf is installed in some non-standard location, what should I do to let it found by find_package(Protobuf)?

Maybe CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH can do it, but it is ugly because other find_package commands will also look into this location.  What I am looking for is something similar to BOOST_ROOT for Find_package(Boost), which is used by find_package(Protobuf) only.

Could anyone give some hint?  The OS I am working on is Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, this variable (referenced [here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables)) specifies additional prefix paths where applications and/or libraries are installed. It causes the find modules, and other related calls, to look in this prefix in addition to the standard ones on each platform. If you had protobuf in /home/user/prefix then using

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:PATH=/home/user/prefix ../src
```

from the build directory would cause CMake to look in /home/user/prefix for protobuf. We use this approach to force CMake to look in a user-local install prefix in addition to the system path.